# Nodejs post large amount of data - 10 MB

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, large-data

I want to post large amount of data (around 10MB) to a nodejs(loopback) api server. My requirement is to ensure that the node server does not miss any api request coming towards it, even if other data is processing at the same time. This api will be called frequently from the scheduler.

Since there is a limit in config.json in loopback folder structure, which specifies the max limit of data to be sent. Is there any challenges to post these much amount of data to an api url(POST method)?

Or is there any mechanism to deal with the large amount of data, so that it will not affect the server performance when process these data.?

Comment: Use `Streams` to handle large set of datas..

Comment: So, while posting I have to write the data in a file and post it rt? and in the receiver side, I need to use the streams to read the data rt?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TUS](https://tus.io/), an open protocol for resumable file uploads. It also has an official [JavaScript client library](https://github.com/tus/tus-js-client). Here is an upload example borrowed from the JS library's Github page:

```
input.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    // Get the selected file from the input element
    var file = e.target.files[0]

    // Create a new tus upload
    var upload = new tus.Upload(file, {
        endpoint: "http://localhost:1080/files/",
        retryDelays: [0, 1000, 3000, 5000],
        metadata: {
            filename: file.name,
            filetype: file.type
        },
        onError: function(error) {
            console.log("Failed because: " + error)
        },
        onProgress: function(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal) {
            var percentage = (bytesUploaded / bytesTotal * 100).toFixed(2)
            console.log(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, percentage + "%")
        },
        onSuccess: function() {
            console.log("Download %s from %s", upload.file.name, upload.url)
        }
    })

    // Start the upload
    upload.start()
}
```

For handling the upload on the server side, you can find multiple node packages in the npm repo. [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tus-node-server) is an example.

Comment: Mu requirement is not file upload. The api pushing is happening from the node server to another node server.